# How could I determine which are the best friends of a Facebook application user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm currently trying to create a Facebook application with the Facebook PHP SDK.

I would like to retrieve which of the user's friends are his best friends, or the one he's most talking with.

Do you know an algorithm or a tip to get them?

Comment: I dont think there is any API call for this.. you have to fetch some data from facebook and have to do some processing on your end.

Comment: fetch there wall/feed, populate an array with there friends ids, do some magik to count the unique ids

Comment: Good idea Lawrence, thanks :)

Comment: They have this built but not accessible to apps.  See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10820251/265570).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, look for markers of friendship, give each activity a weight, total up the "friend score", and appropriate by the age of the friendship (if you're looking for a "lifetime" score). You could look at different timeframes, such as "recent best friends", etc.

I'm not phenomenally familiar with Facebook's Graph API, but if you could access the age of the friend and the number of comments/wall posts they exchange, you'd have some kind of information to go on. Think of other markers like the number of photos they're jointly tagged in, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I've ran into this same issue in the app I'm working on, and open-sourced the code I've used, albeit in Ruby:

https://github.com/mikejarema/facebook-friend-rank

This is a web service which takes an active access token & user id and (assuming a read_stream permission has been granted) returns a hash of ids to counts which can be used for sorting within your application.

The friend rank algorithm looks at a user's 500 most recent interactions (activity feed) and tallies up the frequency of all friends appearing there. The result gives a reasonable ordering of friends, best to worst, and it also works on subsets of friends (eg. sorting mutual friends).

As mentioned in other answers, there's lots of room for exploring photo tags, mutual friend counts, and also looking for the type of interactions (eg. a checkin with a friend is probably a better measure of closeness than a like on their status).

Here's a sample app using this approach and Friend Rank on the backend:

http://facebook-friend-rank.herokuapp.com/demo/index.html

Comment: This is great! Although slow, it seems to work pretty well when I tested it on myself.

Comment: I'd argue that anything (aside from FB revealing an API call) will take a substantial amount of time to run. Even this project's naïve implementation is only 5 calls. I've built in an async mode so that intermediate results are available reasonably fast (eg. 1-2 secs). Keep in mind, this is an imperfect science so its possible that the intermediate results may be 'good enough'.

Comment: True true :) How much of that time is waiting for FQL calls as opposed to parsing?

20% was fairly good, although some in the top 20 confused me. By 40% it was accurate enough to use for displaying more relevant info to a user. After that I think one could continue the calculation on the server for use next time the user came back or refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

I quiet often need to get the list of people user is interacting most with ("best friends", in a Facebook terminology). Took a while to build the class and it is far from being perfect. However, this will save some time to people who are looking where to start.

https://github.com/anuary/ay-fb-friend-rank

The Jun 11, 2012 revision follows these rules to build friend score.

> 1. The applications looks through user's feed entries.
>      1.1. Friend who liked user's feed is given 'feed_like' score.
>      1.2. Friend who commented on user's feed is given 'feed_comment' score.
>      1.3. Friend who addressed user in his feed (whether by posting directly on his wall or tagging in the user) is given 'feed_addressed'
>      score.
> 2. Photos.
>      2.1. If user was tagged by a friend in a photo, profile is given 'photo_tagged_user_by_friend'.
>      2.2. If user tagged a friend in a photo, profile is given 'photo_tagged_friend_by_user'.
>      2.3. Profile will get 'photo_like' for liking a picture either uploaded by the user or a photo where user is tagged.
>      2.4. Profile will get 'photo_comment' for commenting a picture either uploaded by the user or a photo where user is tagged.
> 3. Friends.
>      3.1. Profile will get 'friend_mutual' score for every mutual friend.
> 4. Inbox.
>      4.1. Every profile gets 'inbox_in_conversation' for participating in a conversation with user.
>      4.2. A reparate score is given per every message for any converasation where only two people had a conversation 'inbox_chat'.  photos either
>      uploaded by user or where user is tagged.

Comment: Guy, I am hoping to check this out, but the github.com link is broken.

Comment: Yes teh link is not wiorking