# Combining Facebook friends array from likes and comments

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following code to go through a Facebook user's status and sort all of the friends that liked or commented on the status. Then I add all of those friends to my DB. The problem I'm having is simply combining the two foreach loops. I tried array_combine but that did not work as I still get a lot of duplicate Facebook users that either comment multiple times on a status or comment and like a status.

Any help is wonderfully appreciated. (Code used from this answer: [Facebook Graph API - Finding a users top friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020910/facebook-graph-api-finding-a-users-top-friends))

```
    $statuses = $facebook->api('/me/statuses');
    $user_info = $facebook->api('/me');
    $facebook_id = $user_info['id'];
    foreach($statuses['data'] as $status){
    // processing likes array for calculating fanbase.  


    foreach(($status['likes']['data']) as $likesData){
    $frid = $likesData['id']; 
    $frname = $likesData['name']; 
    $friendArray[$frid] = $frname;
    if($frid!=$facebook_id){
    echo $frid .' ';
    echo $frname .' ';}}

    foreach($status['comments']['data'] as $comArray){
    // processing comments array for calculating fanbase
    $frid = $comArray['from']['id'];
    $frname = $comArray['from']['name'];
    if($frid!=$facebook_id){
    echo $frid .' ';
    echo $frname .' ';}}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an array that you add all the id:s that has either commented or liked the status. Before adding it to the array check that it doesn't exists already.

```
if(!in_array($id, $user_ids_that_liked_or_commented))
{
    $user_ids_that_liked_or_commented[] = $id;
}
```

After you've gone through all likes and comments, add all the values from there to the database.