# How can I get user's best friends throught Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am designing an App for iPhone and I want the user to share my App to his or her best friends. Now I can get user's friendlist throught Facebook Graph API. But how could I find user's best friends? I have an idea that I can use the user's wall to find which friend often appears on the wall. However, some pages and famous people like Obama always appears on the wall. Could someone give a feasible solution?

Comment: You may want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020910/facebook-graph-api-finding-a-users-top-friends.

Answer (score 0):

Define “best friends”, please.

If that is supposed to be something based on the user’s personal perspective at the very moment – then probably best to just let them choose their “best friends” the want to a request to themselves via a simple multi-friend selector.

Or are you referring to a user’s list of “close friends”, the *default* friend list on Facebook that every user can add friends to? That’s available via API, check the `/me/friendlists` connection. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/

Comment: I think it is complicated if you want the user to choose their friends to share. So I want to suggest some friends to the user to share to.

Comment: What’s _complicated_ about that? Use a multi-friend selector with a build-in filter mechanism that starts filtering the friends shown as soon as the user types … I think this would be way better than just suggesting friends to him, because the user themselves might be best able to tell which of their friends might even be _interested_ in such a request, whereas which others just might consider it spam – I think I know my FB friends better in that regard, than any app or automated list might … […]

Comment: [Cont.] What you could do, though, is make use of the “closest friends” list I mentioned, and have those friends on there sorted on top of the list. That’s what I’d consider an acceptable compromise between user comfort on the one side, and “freedom of choice” (whom to send a request to) on the other.