# Facebook Graph 2.4 SDK v5 Closer Friends Php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i used facebook graph 2.4 version and sdk v5.
I wanna know if exists a algorithm to calculate best friend, how is in older version.

My app is a game,sow i recieve just invitable_friends.

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/invitable_friends?fields=id,name,first_name,score,display_name,picture.width(120).height(130)&limit=300',$_SESSION['facebookses']);
$graph = $response->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
```

It's possible?Tnx and sorry for my eng.

Comment: you mean close friends?

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking. I don’t know of any “algorithm to calculate best friend” that would have been available in older API versions. Facebook does not provide any such classification.

Comment: invitable_friends is for inviting friends to games with a canvas implementation, not for anything else.

Comment: maybe he means "friend with the most mutual friends". i´ve created a test app for that some years ago, but it´s not possible anymore because you only get friends who authorized your app too.

Comment: or maybe he means "sort by date on which user added to friendlist"

Comment: @luschn: Mutual friend count is still available though (for two users that are using your app), via the social context.

Comment: yeah, but my guess it that he wants it for all users, seeing that he tried to use invitiable_friends...too unspecific to say though :)

Answer (score 0):

Close friends, like who said here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6166864/5435958

But is not good this option any more.